# C++ exprtk - can it be used within a class?

Tags: c++, class, nested, exprtk

I want to call a function of a class from exprtk.
(http://www.partow.net/programming/exprtk/)

I want to register a function with this toolkit with symbol_table.add_function.
Therefore it is required to derive my class like this from ifunction provided with that toolkit:

```
 template <typename T>
   struct foo : public exprtk::ifunction<T>
   {
      foo() : exprtk::ifunction<T>(0)
      {}

      T operator()()
      {
         // here I want to access data from a class which owns this struct
      }
   };
```

Is it possible to include this struct in a way, that a class can access it and the operator() of this struct can access data in the class?
One possibility would be to pass a pointer of that class to the constructor of the struct. Is there a better way?

Comment: A pointer would be one option. Another option could be to pass a reference instead. A third option could be to use multiple inheritance i.e. deriving `foo` from `exprtk::ifunction<>` _and_ your other class. Without more context it is hard to say which one is the best (or most appropriate). This said, some ad.: If you don't need the complete power of exprtk, you may consider to build your own expression parser. This might be a start: [SO: The Tiny Calculator Project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46965151/7478597).

Comment: So it looks like I have to pass a pointer/reference. Multiple inheritance is not an option, because I need several such functions and each time operator() is called from exprtk.

Comment: "Multiple inheritance is not an option, because I need several such functions and each time operator() is called from exprtk." Multiple inheritance doesn't prevent overloading of `operator()()` or usage in exprtk. But if instances of multiple classes (inherited from exprtk::ifunction<T>) have to share the data of the same instance of your class _then_ multi inheritance is, of course, not an option. In that case, pointer or reference...

Answer (score 0):

The state/data class can either own the `ifunction` or be passed in as a reference (be sure to manage life-times properly) or via a `std::shared_ptr` to the `ifunction` instance:

```
class my_class
{};

template <typename T>
struct foo : public exprtk::ifunction<T>
{
   foo(my_class& mc)
   : exprtk::ifunction<T>(0)
   , mc_(mc)
   {}

   T operator()()
   {
      return mc_.get_some_value() / 2;
   }

   my_class mc_;
};
```

Comment: Finally, I used a different solution. I derived classes/structs from exprtk::expression, exprtk::parser, exprtk::function_compositor and exprtk::symbol_table and used them as member variables of my class. I set the variables (which can be any number now) by using symbol_table::add_variable.