# How do I store a pointer to a derived class in an instance variable declared as a pointer to a base class?

Tags: c++, abstract-syntax-tree

I am trying to write a toy language interpreter in C++. I am having trouble with the AST classes. The parent `ASTNode` class declares its left-branch and right-branch pointers as `ASTNode*`like this:

```
class ASTNode {

    public:
        ASTNode(NodeType newType, const ASTNode* left, const ASTNode* right);

        const ASTNode* getLeft() const;
        const ASTNode* getRight() const;

    protected:
        //node type omitted
        ASTNode* left;
        ASTNode* right;

}
```

The `ASTNode` class has a subclass called ValNode. It has a method that returns its value (stored in a member variable):

```
class ValNode : public ASTNode
{
    public:
        explicit ValNode(const Variant& newvalue);

        const Variant& getValue() const;

    private:
        Variant value;
}
```

When I execute the following code, the program crashes due to a failed `dynamic_cast`. What's wrong, and how can I fix it?

```
ASTNode* node = new ASTNode(NodeType::OP, new ValNode(1), new ValNode(2));
cout << dynamic_cast<const ValNode*>(node->getLeft())->getValue() << endl;
```

Comment: Could you please post definition of the classes?

Comment: I assume left and right are not assigned in the ctor. Otherwise you would probably get a "assignment discards qualifiers" (const) error from the compiler.

Comment: Don't use dynamic_cast. Do you think you need dynamic_cast? This means your design is broken at its core (or doesn't exist). I cannot fix your design but in general you should avoid data members in abstract classes, avoid deriving from concrete classes, and do all your polymorphic work in virtual functions.

Comment: @cli_hlt The constructor parameters are deep copied in the constructor.

Comment: @Techgineer I can't spot `Variant`? How does the `Variant` class/type comply with `ASTNode*`? Need to use a `dynamic_cast` is a serious _code/design smell_ BTW.

Comment: @TheDude Variant is a class that holds any primitive type and strings. It is unrelated to my problem.

Comment: @Techgineer _"It is unrelated to my problem. "_ Eeeer! The `dynamic_cast` fails on it but it's unrelated, sure. See my finger drawing down my lower lid.

Comment: @TheDude GDB clearly shows that the `dynamic_cast` fails and returns `nullptr`. I could have written `dynamic_cast<ValNode*>(node->getLeft())->getLeft()` and had the same problem.

Comment: @Techgineer Well, we can't tell from your insufficient code example. How did you populate that tree for example? Post a [MCVE] please.

Comment: I once posted an AST as part of my answer to [SO: Parsing strings of user input using the cparse library from git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46965151/7478597).

Comment: @Techgineer *It is unrelated to my problem* -- Ok, so if that's the case, get [this to compile without error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ef4aaa23726f014d).

Comment: @PaulMckenzie Edited. Now it does

Comment: @Techgineer: "*The constructor parameters are **deep copied** in the constructor*" - that is a very suspicious statement. Please provide a [mcve] showing your actual `ASTNode` constructor implementation, not just its declaration.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to do a dynamic cast here.
You can use:

```
static_cast<const ValNode*>(node->getLeft())->getValue()
```

Comment: When I do that, I get undefined behavior.

Comment: Please clarify what do you mean by "undefined behavior".

Comment: Random numbers that are clearly unrelated to the input

Comment: This hints that probably one of your constructors is not working properly. Please provide the constructors for ValNode and ASTNode.