# Graphing Calculator Parsing

Tags: c++, parsing

This is for a school project where I am supposed to create a calculator that will graph functions. The graphing works, however my function that actually turns functions (the math kind) into data is not working for two major test case types, and I have no clue how to fix this. The test cases are input = -x^2 and input = x^2+2x+1, both of which when think through what I have written should work. I have been stumped by this for a while now, and I have not found a solution that does not mess up other equations.

```
double Solver(string input, double xValue)
{
int pos1;
int pos2;
int symbolpos;

string substring;

double value1;
double value2;

int count;

while (input.find_first_of(" ") != string::npos)
{
    input.erase(input.find_first_of(" "), 1);
}

while (input.find("(") != string::npos && input.find(")") != string::npos)
{
    pos1 = input.find_first_of("(");

    if (pos1 > 0 && input[pos1 - 1] != '-')
    {
        input.insert(pos1, "*");
        pos1++;
    }
    if (pos1 == 2 && input[0] == '-')
    {
        input.insert(pos1 - 1, "1");
        pos1++;
    }
    pos2 = pos1;
    count = 1;

    while (count != 0)
    {
        pos2++;
        if (input[pos2] == '(')
            count++;
        if (input[pos2] == ')')
            count--;
    }

    substring = to_string(Solver(input.substr(pos1 + 1, pos2 - pos1 - 1), xValue));
    input.replace(pos1, pos2 - pos1 + 1, substring);
}

while (input.find("x") != string::npos)
{
    pos1 = input.find_first_of("x");
    if (pos1 > 0)
    {
        input.insert(pos1, "*");
        pos1++;
    }
    if (pos1 == 2 && input[0] == '-')
    {
        input.insert(pos1 - 1, "1");
        pos1++;
    }
    input.replace(pos1, 1, to_string(xValue));
}

while (input.find("--") != string::npos)
{
    input.replace(input.find("--"), 2, "+");
}

input = parsing(input, '^');
input = parsing(input, '*');
input = parsing(input, '/');
input = parsing(input, '+');
input = parsing(input, '-');


return stod(input);
}


string parsing(string tInput, char searchChar)
{
string input = tInput;
int pos1, pos2, symbolpos;
double value1, value2;
string substring;

while (input.substr(1).find_first_of(searchChar) != string::npos)
{
    symbolpos = input.find_last_of(searchChar);
    pos1 = 0;
    for (int a = 0; a < symbolpos - 1; a++)
    {
        if (input[a] == '^')
            pos1 = a++;
        if (input[a] == '*')
            pos1 = a++;
        if (input[a] == '/')
            pos1 = a++;
        if (input[a] == '+')
            pos1 = a++;
        if (input[a] == '-')
            pos1 = a;
    }

    pos2 = input.size();
    for (int a = input.size(); a > symbolpos + 1; a--)
    {
        if (input[a] == '^')
            pos2 = a--;
        if (input[a] == '*')
            pos2 = a--;
        if (input[a] == '/')
            pos2 = a--;
        if (input[a] == '+')
            pos2 = a--;
        if (input[a] == '-')
            pos2 = a--;
    }
    value1 = stod(input.substr(pos1, symbolpos - pos1));
    value2 = stod(input.substr(symbolpos + 1, pos2 - symbolpos));
    if (searchChar == '^')
        substring = to_string(pow(value1, value2));
    if (searchChar == '*')
        substring = to_string(value1 * value2);
    if (searchChar == '/')
        substring = to_string(value1 / value2);
    if (searchChar == '+')
        substring = to_string(value1 + value2);
    if (searchChar == '-')
        substring = to_string(value1 - value2);
    input.replace(pos1, pos2 - pos1, substring);
}

return input;
```

}

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You have the error cases and that puts you in great position to use the debugging software that should have come with your development environment.  Step through the program and see where the program does something you don't expect.

Comment: Even when you aren't using Bison, its [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/) includes some excellent resources for parsing in general, and it has a full calculator demo.

Comment: Do you have to roll your own parser or can you use a library?  If using a library is an option, you take a look at my project [Boost Matheval](https://github.com/hmenke/boost_matheval).

Comment: I once wrote an answer to a similar question: [SO: Parsing strings of user input using the cparse library from git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46965151/7478597). (I recommended (and showed how) to write it in "pure" C++ instead of using those cparse lib.) Meanwhile, I recognized that other, similar Q/As already existed.