# Pass a function of object of any type to another object in C++

Tags: c++

I'm creating a node system (similar to eg. UE4 or Blender's Cycles) in which i can create nodes of different types and use them later. At the moment I have 2 classes of nodes with output functions like these:

```
class InputInt
{
public:
    int output()
    {
        int x;
        std::cin>>x;
        return x;
    }
};

class RandomInt
{
public:
    int rand10()
    {
        int x;
        x = rand()%10;
        return x;
    }
    int rand100()
    {
        int x;
        x = rand()%100;
        return x;
    }
};
```

I don't pass anything to these nodes. Now I want to create a node which takes and output function from and object of one of above classes. Here is how I implemented it to use `InputInt` node only:

```
class MultiplyBy2
{
    typedef int (InputInt::*func)();

    func input_func;
    InputInt *obj;

public:
    MultiplyBy2(InputInt *object, func i): obj(object), input_func(i) {}
    int output()
    {
        return (obj->*input_func)()*2;
    }
};
```

Having this I can create and use object of `MultiplyBy2` in `main()` and it works perfectly.

```
int main()
{
    InputInt input;
    MultiplyBy2 multi(&input, input.output);
    std::cout<<multi.output()<<std::endl;
}
```

It doesn't obviously work for object of `RandomInt` as I have to pass `*InputInt` object to `MultiplyBy2` object. Is there a way to make `MultiplyBy2` take any kind of an object with its output function eg. like this?

```
int main()
{
    RandomInt random;
    MultiplyBy2 multi2(&random, random.rand10);
    std::cout<<multi2.output()<<std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [The Tiny Calculator Project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46965151/7478597) there I modeled something similar as Abstract Syntax Tree (with execution feature). I believe, this solved it by a little bit different design of classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative approach, using a common base class with virtual methods:

```
#include <iostream>

struct IntOp {
  virtual int get() = 0;
};

struct ConstInt: IntOp {
  int n;
  explicit ConstInt(int n): n(n) { }
  virtual int get() override { return n; }
};

struct MultiplyIntInt: IntOp {
  IntOp *pArg1, *pArg2;
  MultiplyIntInt(IntOp *pArg1, IntOp *pArg2): pArg1(pArg1), pArg2(pArg2) { }
  virtual int get() override { return pArg1->get() * pArg2->get(); }
};

int main()
{
  ConstInt i3(3), i4(4);
  MultiplyIntInt i3muli4(&i3, &i4);
  std::cout << i3.get() << " * " << i4.get() << " = " << i3muli4.get() << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
3 * 4 = 12
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f02aedc7fe83f320)</kbd>

---

As I mentioned `std::function` in post-answer conversation with OP, I fiddled a bit with this idea and got this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct MultiplyIntInt {
  std::function<int()> op1, op2;
  MultiplyIntInt(std::function<int()> op1, std::function<int()> op2): op1(op1), op2(op2) { }
  int get() { return op1() * op2(); }
};

int main()
{
  auto const3 = []() -> int { return 3; };
  auto const4 = []() -> int { return 4; };
  auto rand100 = []() -> int { return rand() % 100; };
  MultiplyIntInt i3muli4(const3, const4);
  MultiplyIntInt i3muli4mulRnd(
    [&]() -> int { return i3muli4.get(); }, rand100);
  for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) {
    std::cout << i << ".: 3 * 4 * rand() = "
      << i3muli4mulRnd.get() << '\n';
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1.: 3 * 4 * rand() = 996
2.: 3 * 4 * rand() = 1032
3.: 3 * 4 * rand() = 924
4.: 3 * 4 * rand() = 180
5.: 3 * 4 * rand() = 1116
6.: 3 * 4 * rand() = 420
7.: 3 * 4 * rand() = 1032
8.: 3 * 4 * rand() = 1104
9.: 3 * 4 * rand() = 588
10.: 3 * 4 * rand() = 252
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/99ed9a3bdf69ec2c)</kbd>

With `std::function<>`, class methods, free-standing functions, and even lambdas can be used in combination. So, there is no base class anymore needed for nodes. Actually, even nodes are not anymore needed (explicitly) (if a free-standing function or lambda is not counted as "node").

---

I must admit that graphical dataflow programming was subject of my final work in University (though this is a long time ago). I remembered that I distinguished

- demand-driven execution vs.
- data-driven execution.

Both examples above are demand-driven execution. (The result is requested and "pulls" the arguments.)

So, my last sample is dedicated to show a simplified data-driven execution (in principle):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

struct ConstInt {
  int n;
  std::vector<std::function<void(int)>> out;
  ConstInt(int n): n(n) { eval(); }
  void link(std::function<void(int)> in)
  {
    out.push_back(in); eval();
  }
  void eval()
  {
    for (std::function<void(int)> &f : out) f(n);
  }  
};

struct MultiplyIntInt {
  int n1, n2; bool received1, received2;
  std::vector<std::function<void(int)>> out;
  void set1(int n) { n1 = n; received1 = true; eval(); }
  void set2(int n) { n2 = n; received2 = true; eval(); }
  void link(std::function<void(int)> in)
  {
    out.push_back(in); eval();
  }
  void eval()
  {
    if (received1 && received2) {
      int prod = n1 * n2;
      for (std::function<void(int)> &f : out) f(prod);
    }
  } 
};

struct Print {
  const char *text;
  explicit Print(const char *text): text(text) { }
  void set(int n)
  {
    std::cout << text << n << '\n';
  }
};

int main()
{
  // setup data flow
  Print print("Result: ");
  MultiplyIntInt mul;
  ConstInt const3(3), const4(4);
  // link nodes
  const3.link([&mul](int n) { mul.set1(n); });
  const4.link([&mul](int n) { mul.set2(n); });
  mul.link([&print](int n) { print.set(n); });
  // done
  return 0;
}
```

With the dataflow graph image (provided by koman900 – the OP) in mind, the `out` vectors represent outputs of nodes, where the methods `set()`/`set1()`/`set2()` represent inputs.

[image: Snapshot of a dataflow graph in Blender]

Output:

```
Result: 12
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4dd300692eeb0dff)</kbd>

After connection of graph, the source nodes (`const3` and `const4`) may push new results to their output which may or may not cause following operations to recompute.

For a graphical presentation, the operator classes should provide additionally some kind of infrastructure (e.g. to retrieve a name/type and the available inputs and outputs, and, may be, signals for notification about state changes).

---

Surely, it is possible to combine both approaches (data-driven and demand-driven execution). (A node in the middle may change its state and requests new input to push new output afterwards.)

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but with this approach I think I wouldn't be able to create many outputs for one node, eg. `RandomInt` has 2 different outputs and I would like to specify which output I want to use. If there is a way to do that with your approach I would be thankful for explanation.

Comment: @koman900 As in `ConstInt`, you can make such operators parametric. You could also introduce `VarInt` or `Assignment` (but this would break the pure functional approach it has in this state).

Comment: @koman900 But I agree, in this design: one class - one type of operator. (I would call it functor even without the `operator()()`.) I didn't consider this as limitation...

Comment: I think this image of node structure in Blender's Cycles is a proper explanation of that: [link](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/58586fa5ebbd1a60e7d76d3e/t/594b3bec8419c2312790e7e0/1498102947950/?format=750w). In this example we can use 2 different outputs for most of the nodes.

Comment: @koman900 Ah - a dataflow language. (I didn't see the image before.) For this case, I would introduce functors which can output tuple like types. (This way, we did it in our professional software.) ...and a type system. But this needs a bit more lines than in the above code. :-)

Comment: @koman900 I could make the `get()` parametric but finally it end's up in something like in acade's answer. (May be, it's worth to mention `std::function` which would make things very flexible.) So, I guess you got two approaches and may combine them to what you intend to do.

Comment: @koman900 If you intend to make a GUI for the data flow, then I would suggest a base class with some kind of reflection (to retrieve input(s) and output(s) from operator nodes).

Comment: @koman900 I added a 3rd example and some notes about data-driven vs. demand-driven execution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [templates](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/templates).

```
template <typename UnderlyingClass>
class MultiplyBy2
{
    typedef int (UnderlyingClass::*func)();

    func input_func;
    UnderlyingClass *obj;

public:
    MultiplyBy2(UnderlyingClass *object, func i) : obj(object), input_func(i) {}
    int output()
    {
        return (obj->*input_func)() * 2;
    }
};

int main()
{
    // test
    InputInt ii;
    MultiplyBy2<InputInt> mii{ &ii, &InputInt::output };
    RandomInt ri;
    MultiplyBy2<RandomInt> mri{ &ri, &RandomInt::rand10 };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit convoluted. However I think you should be making an interface or class that returns a value and the objects should inherit from this. Then the operator class can take any class that inherits from the base/interface. Eg Make an BaseInt class that stores an int and has the output method/ RandomInt and InputInt should inherit from BaseInt

Comment: That's what I implemented in my answer. :-) (Except that I used a method `get()` instead of overloading the `operator()()`.)